# How to prevent downloading video files from my website ? Like https://nichevid.com

Tags: security

I know this question asked many time but there are always answered that it is not possible. I want to say that if it is not possible then HOW 'NICHEVID' team do this. All hosted videos are safe and all software(ex. IDM, DAP) fails to download it.

Comment: The only way is to not serve the videos; anything that is served to client **is** downloaded by definition. Even if you take full control over my PC, I'll record the screen with my phone's camera.

Comment: More tags help accumulating downvotes

Comment: @someone Does't Matter if you will record from camera. I want to stop downloading it. Take a look  https://nichevid.com

Comment: You **can not** stop a client from downloading it if you want the client to see the video.

Answer (score 1):

## You can't.

It is simply not possible to stop the client from downloading a video if you want them to see it. The reason is simple: If you want them to see a video, you need to show it to them. Without access to the video data, the client cannot display the video.

---

## What can you do?

You could obfuscate the process as much as possible by writing your own video player and throwing as much cryptography at it as possible - hypothetically speaking of course - and only loading chunks of it to reduce how much video data the client keeps in memory. But even then you still need to transmit the data *and* the player, as well as all keys to the application. Afterall, your client *needs* all this data to play the video.

In the end, it'll be a battle between you and the user. I always like to think of the **20/80 rule**: With 20% effort you can get 80% result, generally.

So if you just obfuscate your process a little bit (20% effort) you can stop about 80% of all users from a simple `Right-Click -> Save As...`. That might be good enough for you. Just keep in mind that there is *always* a way to circumvent your obfuscation - no matter how much you try, someone will get to the video if they want it enough.

Answer (score 1):

I was interested to check out [nichevid.com](https://nichevid.com/), which you referred to. You claim that they "*do not allow videos to be downloaded*", but I can't see them actually claiming that outright.

Sure, they obfuscate HTML and other stuff as much as possible to make it difficult to download videos, and this will help - but it seems to me that **the main thing they do to keep videos secure is authentication:**

From a page describing their security model:

> An unauthorized person cannot view your content.
>
> (...)
>
> Only authenticated users that you have defined, or you have approved
>   to access the system, can get the content on their screen.  
>   An unauthorized person cannot download your content. 
>   The content is streamed, never downloaded. 
>   The transmission of the content is encrypted. 
>   The transmission channel is digitally signed with an expiration date.
>  
>   The video link on the page is “obfuscated” so that harvesting tools cannot recognize that a video is on the page.

Most of this seems to have to do with either *encryption during transmission* - i.e. using HTTPS - or obfuscation. The video still needs to be decrypted when it reaches the client, to the key phrase in all of this is in reality the two words ***"authenticated users"***.

They also include the following disclaimer at the bottom:

> It is not possible to protect against every eventuality that can be
>   encountered by a motivated expert hacker. (...) While we cannot
>   guarantee your content cannot be acquired by someone who should not
>   have it, we certainly make it far more attractive to attack someone
>   else.

So as mentioned by others, both in answers and comments above: You can obfuscate stuff to make it harder to download videos, and you can limit accessibility through user authentication, but there's simply no way to control access to a video entirely if you want it to be able to run on an end-user's PC / Phone / tablet / whatever.

Source: https://blog.nichevid.com/niche-video-media-security-model/